# Spark createdataframe cannot infer schema - default data types?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, schema, databricks

I am creating a spark dataframe in databricks using createdataframe and getting the error:

```
'Some of types cannot be determined after inferring'
```

I know I can specify the schema, but that does not help if I am creating the dataframe each time with source data from an API and they decide to restructure it.

Instead I would like to tell spark to use 'string' for any column where a data type cannot be inferred.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

This can be easily handled with schema evaluation with `delta` format. Quick ref: https://databricks.com/blog/2019/09/24/diving-into-delta-lake-schema-enforcement-evolution.html

Comment: the question is about `spark.createDataFrame` function, not reading from Delta table

Comment: Thanks Karthikeyan, that's helpful for the use case described but as Alex says doesn't quite get what I want - i.e avoiding specifying the schema in full up front.